# Monacaでデバッグビルドは完了も、端末にインストールできない。

Tags: monaca

Monacaでデバッグビルドは完了するのですが、apkファイルを端末(androd7.0)にダウンロードして開こうとすると、「パッケージの解析中に問題が発生しました。」と出てインストールできません。(端末のmonacaデバッガーでは動きます。)
該当のapkファイルは他のスマフォ(androd6.0.1)でインストールができてますので、androdのバージョンによるものかと思うのですが、対処方法が見つけられません。ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授の頂ければ幸いです。
なお、確認した端末は以下の通りです。
androd7.0の端末：Xperia Z5 SO-01H 
androd6.0.1の端末：VAIO Phone A(Android OS 搭載モデル)VPA0511S 
以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これだけの情報では原因を突き止めるのは難しいです。ご推察の通りAndroidのバージョンによるものではないかと思いますが、具体的にビルド時の設定や手順などを詳細に追記されると原因が判明するかもしれません。

Comment: Android6.0はOKでAndroid7.0がNGということはAndroidManifest.xmlのmaxSdkVersionで6.0までしかインストールできない指定にされている可能性があります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。解決にはなっていませんが、とりあえずインストールすることが出来ましたので、ご報告いたします。調べているうちにコンテンツ内の画像ファイルの欠落を見つけこれを追加をし、アパッチを立ち上げ端末からブラウザーでapkファイルをダウンロードしたところ、無事インストールを完了できました。なお、QRコードによるインストールは状況は変わりませんでした。

Comment: AndroidManifest.xmlについては、調べてみます。初めての投稿なので勝手がわからずご迷惑をお掛けし恐縮です。

Comment: いえいえ迷惑などとんでもないです。コメントで促されて情報を追記していくのは正常なやりとりなので問題ありません。